# Drupal Multilingual Emails

Tags: emails, i18n-l10n

We have a multilingual website set up and functioning fine.  The next step was to setup translations for the default Drupal account emails (e.g. Welcome, Account activation, Account blocked etc).  This is also done - and our client can go in and add translations for each of these.

The issue is - the client is asking; seeing as these are default Drupal emails, have the translations already be done for each language?

We have the `l10n_update` module pulling down translate updates to core and each module - but the account emails are not receiving translates.

Does any one know if these emails have already been translated? Can anyone provide some insight? We've searched and haven't come across anything

thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you installed the Internationalization Module, you should have a sub-module called "Variable translation". If enabled, go to admin/config/regional/i18n/variable and choose the variables which you would like to translate.

In your case this would be the ones in the "User Emails" tab. Once checked and activated go to the user e-mail page (admin/config/people/accounts) and click on the different language links at the top of the page to translate.

Comment: Hi Lance - this is already done. We can apply translates fine - but they are all still the default English language. I.e. the French version is still the English version.

When you enable to variable translation - should they already be translated? Or is it up to the client to translate these emails? Basically, the client doesn't want to translate the emails - he assumes they should be translated automatically

Comment: I think they are already translated. If you open the latest french .po file, you see them (https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/fr). So probably you need to import this file to have updated translations?

Comment: Cheers Lance - sorted us out!

Comment: One more Question - I've got the most up to date .po file for the other languages.  I can see the translation there from looking and searching. But it just doesn't appear to show up on the site/when I register in French for example.  Is there a way to force these translations to appear? Cheers

Comment: Cache cleared right? Do you also see them in the "Interface translation"?

Comment: Yeah - cache cleared about 10 times now! And they appear in interface translation.  Odd thing is - e.g. When searching for a string, they are all translated - but when registering a new user under the French flavour - the email is still English.  No matter how many clear caches! Just can't seem to force them to execute

Answer (score 0):

I installed on my local computer a version of Drupal core in the language I needed. I then copied the emails in the right language into my multi-language website.